# How to install Blur Admin?

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower

I have been trying to install `blur-admin` via (`git clone https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin.git`). But when I install it from git bash as mentioned in the installation guide it shows the following error:

> bower                                              ECONFLICT Unable to
>   find suitable version for angular
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>
> npm ERR! node v4.4.5
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! blur_admin@1.2.0 postinstall: `bower install` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the blur_admin@1.2.0 postinstall
>   script 'bower install'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the blur_admin package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     bower install
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs blur_admin
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR! npm ERR!     npm owner ls blur_admin
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\blur-admin\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because **Bower** is not installed in your Windows Machine.
Try to install bower before installing this *AngularJs* template.

Use the following command to install bower:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Also check if **Gulp** - Task automation tool is install or not.

Use the following command to install the same:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Now use `npm install` to install the project and its Package Dependencies.

To **run** the application:

```
gulp serve
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got a little bit late.
Did you try to move the `/bower_components/` folder from the `/client/` directory to your root project directory? That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
npm i -g npm
```

Then delete everything in node_modules. When those are deleted, cd to your directory and

```
npm install
```

Worked for me. If you are on OSX or Linux, use sudo.

If you are on Windows, make sure you're running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from Bower, as Bower is not installed into the system.

First install the bower by following:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then run the app by :

```
gulp serve
```